# megeplaza smtp - Zend error

Tags: magento2.3, zend-framework, smtp, mageplaza

Magento 2.3.1
When I send a test mail, I get this error:

> An exception was raised while creating
>   "Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp\Auth\Login"; no instance returned

Logs:

> main.CRITICAL: An exception was raised while creating
>   "Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp\Auth\Login"; no instance returned
>   {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException

Comment: Have you tried to send using same details outside of magento in an email client? Could be invalid credentials.

Comment: check your login details

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157490)